# How to create a popup message initially before running the program?

Tags: user-interface, matlab

Hye all.

I have a gui program. My question is how can i make my program started with user insert his name first. For example: when the user double click on my program, then there will be a popup message ask the user his name. After the user insert his name, then only the program will run. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to do what you want, just put it at the beginning of the file. This will ask for a name as woodchips suggests, when it is empty or cancel is clicked, the dialog will reappear until a non-empty name is given.

```
%% user authentication
user = '';
while isempty(user)
    user = inputdlg('Please enter your user name:',...
                    'User name',1,{''});
    if isempty(user)
        user = '';
    else
        user = deblank(user{1});   
    end;
end

%% real program code below
```

However, if all you need is the user name (i.e. account name) of your user, you can do this automatically without any user intervention:

```
if ispc
    user = getenv('UserName');
else 
    user = getenv('USER');
end;
```

In Unix/Linux and probably Mac you should be able to probe this a little more by using the finger program (when present on your system). Take a look at the [manpage of finger](http://linux.die.net/man/1/finger) and the matlab command [system](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/system.html) for more information.

Comment: thank you.. its work.. one more question. How i want to create an exit button? For example the user push the exit button and then i want the program to end and popup a message 'Thank You'..

Comment: Generally I would not recommend showing such a dialog, it only hinders the user and when the button is not clicked, it will prevent the program from really ending. But if you need something to do that: take a look at [msgbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/msgbox.html)

Comment: By [hinder](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hinder) I mean the user has to take an extra action to close the application. While you mean well by thanking your user for using your program, most users will dislike the feature, because it slows them down. When they click "close" they want your program to close, perhaps some security from losing their work "Do you want to save your work? Save/Don't save/Cancel", but that's it. You might want to take a look at some books on GUI design (e.g. [Gui Bloopers](http://www.amazon.com/GUI-Bloopers-2-0-Second-Technologies/dp/0123706432))

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the inputdlg function. It pops up a dialog box that asks for input from the user. And you can set the WindowStyle as a "modal" box, so that nothing else can be done until it is satisfied.

Comment: Inputdlg is modal by default.